# This is CRTP usage for static polymorphism but without implementation of a derived function. Compiles both in gcc and visual studio. Why?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, crtp

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Derived>
class Base
{
public:
  void method1()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->method1();
  }

  void method2()
  {
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->method2();
  }
};

class Derived1: public Base<Derived1>
{
public:
  void method1()
  {
    std::cout << "Method 1 of Derived1 executed.\n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Derived1 d1;
  d1.method1();
  d1.method2();
  return 0;
}
```

Follow up question: How to I make this type safe? That is, If someone forgets to implement method2, I would like the compiler to catch it. I don't want this to blow up at runtime.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that such a mistake will be caught during compile time. Any way to make this typesafe?

Comment: You could make it type safe through the basic SFISAE method check system that you'll be able to find in several questions here on SO or with google.

Comment: @Noah: Do you mean SFINAE?  And I don't see how to apply it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the reason that this is valid is that if you instantiate this code:

```
void method2()
{
  static_cast<Derived*>(this)->method2();
}
```

where `Derived` does not have an implementation of `method2()` will essentially be a glorified self-recursive call.  The reason here is that in `Derived1`, there is indeed a member function called `method2`, namely the one inherited from the base class.

I tried running this code, and sure enough the call to `method2` caused a stack overflow from self-recursion.

Normally, the CRTP avoids this by not having the base class function call a derived class function of the same name.  That way, if the derived class is missing a particular function, the call triggers a compiler error.  In your case, this doesn't happen because the function itself could be referenced indirectly from the base class.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Derived1 d1;
  d1.method2();
```

Even though `Derived1` doesn't define `method2()`, it gets it by inheriting `Base` anyway. That is why it compiles and runs. `d1.method2()` actually calls `Base::method2()`, which again calls itself. It's a recursive call.